# File upload with multer returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I'm currently trying to implement file-uploads for my application, in which I use ReactJS, node.js with express, and MongoDB and mongoose. I'm using multer middleware for fileuploads, however, despite looking at all similar questions here on SO and also looking it up, I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my React form:

```
addUser (event) {

    var formfile = new FormData();
    formfile.append("file", this.state.filesToBeSent);

    axios.post('adduser', 
        JSON.stringify({
          entry: this.state.currname,
          passwrd: this.state.currpasswrd,
          formfile : formfile
        }), {
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} 
                }
            )
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.addUser} encType="multipart/form-data" >
            <input value={this.state.currname} />
            <input value={this.state.currpasswrd} />
            <input type="file" value={this.state.filesToBeSent} name="file" />
            <button type="submit" >Add</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

This is my node.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/User.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require("multer");
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cd(null, "./uploads");
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const newFilename = `${uuidv4()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, newFilename);
    },
})

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file + " and exit.");
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm not doing anything with the text-inputs just yet, because I wanted to get the file upload to work first.

I tried out a variety of things, like using `async(req, res)` in `router.post()`. I tried using `x-www-form-urlencoded` as content-type and to only send the file without text-inputs( I specified `formfile` as data to be sent without the whole `JSON.stringify()`, however, I didn't manage to get it to work.

Can anyone spot a mistake in my code? Or does anyone have any other ideas about how to get it to work?

Edit: 
Setting up the adduser-route in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var adduser = require('./routes/adduser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/adduser', adduser);
```

Comment: your backend code is correct , add `console.log(req.file)` ...to see you are receiving file from frontend or not .....it looks like there is some mistake from frontend side.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I already added console.log(req.file) in my function, or where should I add it according to you?

Comment: It is still not enough code, you don't show the complete content of ./routes/adduser.js, there might be an issue there, you need to return the router object. Also I recommend placing app.use("/adduser") before app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); when you setup your routes.

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma I edited my question to show the complete contents of ./routes/adduser. Thank you very much, I will try that immediately

Comment: Looks ok... did swapping app.use('/adduser', adduser) with app.use(express.static, ...) helped?

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma Unfortunately not, I received the same error message. I went back to only receiving data from text-inputs and it worked fine though. SO if the backend looks fine, it should be something with my front-end code, right?

Comment: You may want to check that article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js

Answer (score 0):

Did you test your post endpoint? You can use a rest client such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) just to make sure that this is not the problem. Send a POST request to the endpoint and see if it gets invoked.

Then I guess you should use "/adduser" on your client and not "adduser" if you endpoint is exposed at "localhost:port/adduser". Your code doesn't show how you set up the route in the node.js code.

Finally you may want to use an higher level component to perform the upload, which can handle multipart for you in case you upload larger files. I found the combination [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) + Multer being quite convenient.

Comment: SO, I tested the post endpoint, and I'm getting a 404 not found error message. This seems weird to me as this connection worked earlier when I only had text inputs. When I first started with the application I used "/adduser", however, it did not work therefore I switched to "adduser".
I will update my question to include how I set up the route.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
router.post("/", upload.single("formfile"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.formfile + " and exit.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the headers should be:

```
{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
```

instead of application/json.